# How to update DT datatable in Shiny when within a module and the selection criteria are changed

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I try to make a shiny module to present data from dataframes using the DT package. I would like to use a module to have a standard set up of DT-table options like language and others.

I want the user to be able to select different subsets of the data interactively and thereafter be able to see the data as a DT-table. The selection of the subset will be generated outside the module because I would like the subset to be available for other uses, for example to be exported to a csv-file.

This works as intended when I don't use a module for making the DT table. When I put the code inside a module, a table is produced when the app starts. But when the selection criteria are changed, the table don't update.

I have included an app illustrating the problem. Table 1 is generated without using shiny module and updates as expected when the selection changes. Table 2 is output using the module and don't update when the selection is changed.

I'm running R-studio 1.1.463, R version 3.5.2 and DT version 0.5.

```
require("DT")
require("shiny")

# module for presenting data using DT
showDTdataUI <- function(id) { 
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    DT::dataTableOutput(ns("table"))
  )
  }

showDTdata <- function(input, output, session, DTdata) {
  output$table <- renderDataTable({
      DT::datatable(DTdata)
    })
}

# User interface
ui <- 
  fluidPage(
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(id="DT",
                   width = 4,
                   helpText(h4("Select")),
                   selectInput("selectedSpecies", label = "Species",
                               choices = c("setosa","versicolor","virginica"), 
                               selected = "versicolor")
      ),
      mainPanel(
        h3("Table 1. Presenting selected data from Iris" ),
        DT::dataTableOutput("table"),
        h5(br("")),
        h3("Table 2. Presenting selected data from Iris using shiny module"),
        showDTdataUI(id="testDTModule")
      )
    )
  )


# Define server logic ----
server <- function(session, input, output) {

  selectedIris <- reactive ( {
    selected <- iris[which(iris$Species==input$selectedSpecies),]
    selected
  })

  output$table <- renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(selectedIris())
  })

  callModule(showDTdata, id="testDTModule", DTdata=selectedIris())

}

# Run the app ----
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pass the reactive conductor in `showDTdata`:

```
showDTdata <- function(input, output, session, DTdata) {
  output$table <- renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(DTdata()) # not datatable(DTdata)
  })
}

callModule(showDTdata, id="testDTModule", DTdata=selectedIris) # not DTdata=selectedIris()
```

Comment: Stephane, does this approach have big advantages compared to writing a regular function(x,y,z) and then for instance say: output$Table1 <- renderDataTable({function(...some input arguments...)  I'll add another example answer for you to comment on the difference if you feel like it.

Comment: Thank you! Now it works as intended. And I believe I have learnt a little bit more about functions and reactivity so I hopefully manage better next time.

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want? I removed your functions and added the `selection ='multiple'` to table 1 (`tableX`) so that we can then listen to `tableX_rows_selected`

P.S.: I have noticed that if you first load DT and then shiny, that the whole app won't work anymore. This is a bit weird since we call all datatable functions with DT::... but, you do get a warning message that some parts of DT are masked by shiny or viceversa.

```
require("shiny")
require('DT')


# User interface
ui <- 
    fluidPage(
        sidebarLayout(
            sidebarPanel(id="DT",
                         width = 4,
                         helpText(h4("Select")),
                         selectInput("selectedSpecies", label = "Species",
                                     choices = c("setosa","versicolor","virginica"), 
                                     selected = "versicolor")
            ),
            mainPanel(
                h3("Table 1. Presenting selected data from Iris" ),
                DT::dataTableOutput("tablex"),
                br(),
                h3("Table 2. Presenting selected data from Iris using shiny module"),
                DT::dataTableOutput("table2")

            )
        )
    )


# Define server logic ----
server <- function(session, input, output) {

    values <- reactiveValues(rowselect = numeric())

    selectedIris <- reactive ( {
        selected <- iris[which(iris$Species==input$selectedSpecies),]
        selected
    })

    output$tablex <- renderDataTable({
        DT::datatable(selectedIris(), selection = 'multiple')
    })


    IrisSelected <- reactive({ 
        df <- iris[c(input$tablex_rows_selected), ]
        df
    })


    output$table2 <- renderDataTable({
        req(nrow(IrisSelected()) > 0)
        DT::datatable( IrisSelected())
    })  
}

# Run the app ----
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Let me know whether it helps, and otherwise let me know what is missing

Comment: Regrettably it didn't solve my problem. 
I want a solution were I use a shiny module because I would like to include a lot of code in the module to format the table and I will use it for several tables in the app.
Table 1 is produced without using the module. When the selected species is changed, Table 1 updates as wanted. In contrast, Table 2 does not update when the selected species is changed.
How to get Table 2 (i.e. when using a module) updated when the selection changes?

Comment: I just ran it again, and if you change species, table 1 is redrawn for the new input, and of course then the selected rows are 0, so table two is also recreated as an empty table. I'm not sure what you meant with "table 2 is not update", because it is. But seems Stephane has given us another way to work on it

Comment: I realize now that I misunderstood your original question as well to some extend. I thought you were after a subset of the data by "selecting" things in table one, and then put those into table 2. At least now you also have an example of how to work with selecting rows in one table, and use them for another table.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing of the shiny module approach, I would have probably written it like a normal function. The app below works but I am curious now after seeing the answer by @Stephane what the advantages are of using callModule approach over regular function approach

```
require("DT")
require("shiny")


makeTable <- function(dataframe) { DT::datatable(dataframe) %>% 
                                   formatStyle(names(dataframe), background = '#fff') 
                                  }

# User interface
ui <- 
  fluidPage(
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(id="DT",
                   width = 4,
                   helpText(h4("Select")),
                   selectInput("selectedSpecies", label = "Species",
                               choices = c("setosa","versicolor","virginica"), 
                               selected = "versicolor")
      ),
      mainPanel(
dataTableOutput('Table1')
      )
    )
  )


# Define server logic ----
server <- function(session, input, output) {

  selectedIris <- reactive ( {
    selected <- iris[which(iris$Species==input$selectedSpecies),]
    selected
  })

 output$Table1 <- renderDataTable(makeTable(selectedIris()))
}

# Run the app ----
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```