# Modules in separated server.R and ui.R files

Tags: r, module, shiny

Is it possible to create modules in a Shiny App which is written down in separated app.R, server.R and ui.R files?

All the examples I found are one app.R file with embedded server and ui functions in. See [example 1](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/modules.html), [example 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55329237/how-to-update-dt-datatable-in-shiny-when-within-a-module-and-the-selection-crite)!, example 3!

(I took the code from this last example for this test).

I tried to run this app:

app.R

```
library(shiny)

# load module functions
source("hello_world.R")

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

ui.R

```
#ui.R

library(shiny)
#source("hello_world.R")
ui <- fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Using of Shiny modules"),

  fluidRow(
    # Call interface function of module "hello_world"
    hello_worldUI(id = "id_1")
  )

)
```

server.R

```
#server.R

library(shiny)
source("hello_world.R")


server <- function(input, output, session) {

  # Call logic server function of module "hello_world"
  callModule(module = hello_world, id = "id_1")

}

# UPDATE! -> my Error comes from this line of code  in server.R file: 
#shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server) 
#Removing the line above solve the problem.
```

hello_world.R

```
#module 1: hello_world

# Function for module UI
hello_worldUI <- function(id) {
    ns <- NS(id)

    fluidPage(
        fluidRow(
            column(2, textInput(ns("TI_username"), label = NULL, placeholder = "your name")),
            column(2, actionButton(ns("AB_hello"), label = "Hello !"))
        ),
        hr(),
        fluidRow(
            column(12, textOutput(ns("TO_Hello_user")))
        )
    )

}

# Function for module server logic
hello_world <- function(input, output, session) {

    # When user clicks on "Hello" button : Update reactive variable "name"
    name <- eventReactive(input$AB_hello, {
        return(input$TI_username)
    })

    # Show greetings
    output$TO_Hello_user <- renderText({
        if (name() %in% "") {
            return("Hello world !")
        } else {
            return(paste("Hello", name(), "!"))
        }
    })

}
```

But I got this error:

*Warning: Error in force: object 'ui' not found

  52: force

  51: uiHttpHandler

  50: shinyApp

Error in force(ui) : object 'ui' not found*

Comment: I updated the answer, so now it should be correct.

Answer (score 3):

The `ui` and `server` objects are not known to the app unless you define them in the same file and they are generated at run time, or you explicitly call them from outside files before `shinyApp()`. Change your `app.R` like below, and it should work:

```
library(shiny)

# load module functions
source("hw.R")
# load ui elements
source("ui.R")
# load server function
source("serv.R")

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: At the moment somebody gave me this link before and it contains all that I was needed. I updated my answer based on that. https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/two-file.html